# Some style effects that I don't know how they are named

Tags: border, styling

I am new in coding and i have a project to make and some minor problems I don't know how the circled things. I believe the top one can be made by croping the photo, but i want to find out if there's a html/css way and the margins that go after the content is a big mistery to me. If anyone would be so kind, i will appreciate just naming those things so i can do a little research by myself. The image is located at the following url : http://postimg.org/image/u4lzmixjj/ .

Thank you, Iosif

Comment: I don't know how the circled things are made *

Comment: The top effect does not have a name as far as I know. The other things are similar to ribbons. Try to search for "Photoshop ribbon" (as these effects can't be made in pure CSS -- you'll need a program like Photoshop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can be constructed using a few superimposed shapes as demonstrated in this tutorial:

see: [Pure CSS/HTML Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-practical-css-shapes/)

But more generally these are images created outside html/css, and resized and used as a template/background to place html objects onto.

see: [Image/CSS/HTML Tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/create-a-3d-ribbon-wrap-around-effect-plus-a-free-psd/)

Answer (score 0):

This [tool](http://livetools.uiparade.com/ribbon-builder.html#) is fun to play around with. I would prefer images.